# Incompatible color package and defining a xfloat environment -> " Too many }'s"

Tags: floats, color, incompatibility

I am pepping up a thesis. Among others I am using a package based on *Modified UDO thesis by; Jose A. Flores, November 2011*. Unfortunately, I cannot find the original. One part of the package seems to redefine the `float` definition and I boiled the error down to the following code. I created a small style file: (killer.sty) containing:

```
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
   \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
   \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
                    {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
                     \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
                     \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
                     \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
     }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
\global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup 
\def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
\boxmaxdepth\z@
\hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
}
```

Actually, I have no experience with TeX programming, but from my point of view braces and `if`-`fi` are ok. In the most simple case it compiles (pdflatex) and looks ok. If I put the `color` package, however, it produces following error messages:

```
mini.tex(16): Error: Too many }'s.
mini.tex(16): Error: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.
mini.tex(16): Error: Extra \endgroup.
```

A minimal non-working example looks like this (put your pdf figure): *mini.tex*

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report} % 
%====
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{killer}
\usepackage{color}%this works if this line is commented
%====
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{your.pdf}
        \caption[]{Schematic representation}        
        \label{fig:yourFig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Why is this incompatible with `color`. I was expecting a lot, but not that.

(MikTex 2.9 on Win7 64, SP1)

Comment: That is bizarre I had never heard of that class then someone asked about it yesterday, it uses definitions from an _early_ version of latex2.09 so puts back your document over 25 years.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215028/longtable-formatting-in-list-of-tables#comment504767_215028

Comment: Truly bizarre, as these are definitely  two independent incidents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems very similar to the one in [Problems with TikZ when I change document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191808/problems-with-tikz-when-i-change-document-class)

The solution given there should work also for your setting:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report} % 
%====
\usepackage{graphicx}

% save a copy of \@xfloat
\makeatletter\let\latex@xfloat\@xfloat\makeatother
\usepackage{killer}

% redefine \@xfloat to have the intended behavior
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat\latex@xfloat
\apptocmd{\@xfloat}{\linespread{1}\normalsize}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{color}%this works if this line is commented
%====
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{your.pdf}
        \caption[]{Schematic representation}        
        \label{fig:yourFig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(Don't use `[H]`, you'll regret it if you do.)

If the bad code is in the class (I'll call it `killer`), then do

```
% save a copy of \@xfloat
\makeatletter\let\latex@xfloat\@xfloat\makeatother

\documentclass{killer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% redefine \@xfloat to have the intended behavior
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat\latex@xfloat
\apptocmd{\@xfloat}{\linespread{1}\normalsize}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{color}%this works if this line is commented

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{your.pdf}
        \caption[]{Schematic representation}        
        \label{fig:yourFig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not loading `killer` would be a better fix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @egreg. I agree, not using it, is probably the best solution. Compiling a simple example with and without, I don't see a big difference anyway. So I guess deleting this part from the `UDOthesis.sty` is best (tested: keeps working when removed). Do you agree? Nevertheless, I am curious what it is actually doing. Is it only changing a few distances? I also realize now that only `[h]` but not `[H]` is handled. And why is this making problems with `color`? Luckily @mkunkel from the other post @DavidCarlisle referred to, is not using `color`. (yet?)

Comment: The workaround does the trick, although I use `\documentclass{report}` and `\usepackage{killer}`. But if I understand this correctly, this results in ignoring the `\def\@xfloat` part from killer completely. (see comment above)

Comment: @mikuszefski the latex format colour support needs extra groups to keep colour local to boxes, these `\colour@begingroup` `\color@endgroup` commands are set to `\relax` for compatibility with _latex 2.09_ (ie the 1980s) but made into groups by `color` package. But even if the grouping is fixed, because the code is based on a 1987 latex format it removes everything added since then. `[!ht]` feature, the code to add `H` possibly doesn't match, the code to check the float fits on the page is removed... You could just remove the float part, but the rest of that file is of a similar vintage...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, so I guess most of the stuff it is trying to do, is probably handled better with the new standards anyway. So not using the whole thing at all is probably the best choice.